# custom error type handling after receiving data from internet

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have *RestManager* class which is used to fetch data from Internet

```
class RestManager {

func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<T, ErrorType> {
 
     URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map { $0.data }
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .mapError({ error in
            if let error = error as? URLError {
                switch error.code {
                case .notConnectedToInternet, .timedOut, .networkConnectionLost:
                    return .noInternetConnection
                case .cannotDecodeRawData, .cannotDecodeContentData:
                    return .empty
                default:
                    return .general
                }
            }
            return .general
        })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
}
```

In Repository class there is function *getCountriesList* which, using *RestManager* is returning *AnyPublisher<[Country], ErrorType>* where *ErrorType* represents enum with custom cases for error handling (.noInternetConnection, .general, .empty)

```
class Covid19RepositoryImpl: Covid19Repository {

func getCountriesList() -> AnyPublisher<[Country], ErrorType> {
    let url = RestEndpoints.countriesList.endpoint()
    return RestManager().fetchData(url: url)
}
}
```

In viewModel class, in function *getAllCountries*, pipeline is created for fetching and saving data in *countries* variable, and in *.sink* in *completion* I tried to save *ErrorType* (if there is any error) in specific variable called *error*

I tried to use like this

```
class CountriesViewModelImpl: CountriesViewModel {

var repository: Covid19Repository

@Published var countries: [Country] = []
@Published var error: ErrorType?
@Published var loader: Bool = true

private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = .init()

init(repository: Covid19Repository){
    self.repository = repository
    getAllCountries()
}

func getAllCountries() {
            
   repository
        .getCountriesList()
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink { error in
            self.error = error
            }
        } receiveValue: { [unowned self] newCountries in
            self.countries = newCountries
            self.error = nil
            self.loader = false
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
}
```

But it returns *Cannot assign value of type 'Subscribers.Completion' to type 'ErrorType'*

Is there any other way I can handle error?

Answer (score 2):

[`sink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/sink(receivecompletion:receivevalue:)) returns an enum in the [`receiveCompletion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscribers/completion) closure with `finished` and `failure` cases

```
.sink { completion in
    switch completion {
        case .finished: print("finished")
        case .failure(let error): self.error = error
    }
} receiveValue: ...
```